# React Native with many components

Tags: android, ios, performance, react-native

I'm working on a calendar component which contains a yearly view, where the month cards are laid out in a 3x4 grid. Each month card contains week rows, where each row contains 7 days represented by a `<Text>` component. In this way the year view contains a few hundreds of components and it takes at least 2-300 ms. to render.

As a plus I need to use it in `<ScrollView>`, where the user can scroll prev/next years.

I tried to optimise the layout using absolute positioning, tried to reduce the number of components as I can, however a year view must contain at least 365 `<Text>` for days and another bunch of `<View>` for layout. I tried to defer rendering of the view, but no success.

My question is, before going to implement month card on native side (what I would like to avoid, due to the app must run on iOS and Android as well), if is there any good way to use a view in ReactNative which contains hundreds of child component? Somehow batching it, or move to a separate thread, I do not know.

Comment: Do you have a design requirement as to what it's supposed to look like you could share?  It might spur some ideas of what's possible.

Comment: My design requirement - as I do it for my own app - is to mimic native calendar app (regardless of iOS or Android, they are almost the same) where the user navigate to the calendar view - which is part of a `<Navigator>` stack - and display a Yearly view (12 months) where the user can swipe up/down to go the prev/next year. Clicking on a month card should navigate to a month view and so on.